# Best way to iterate a collection without seeing "Collection modified,enumeration cannot continue..."

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, collections

I have been coming up against the same problem recently whereby I have a collection on a client application that I continually use to update a UI. The collection can be modified by a server push at any time which sometimes causes the exception "Enumeration cannot continue because the collection was modified". I've used various strategies to get around this, such as trapping the error and re-executing the code (feels rubbish) and using synclock which doesn't necessarily lock the collection (I think).

I'm sure this isn't a new problem and I was wondering how other developers have solved this issue.

Comment: What are you doing inside the enumeration loop?

Comment: Don't modify the collection that you are enumerating?

Comment: Patient: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this!" Doctor: "Don't do this."

Answer (score 1):

If the data is not too large I like to freeze collections while I enumerate them:

```
foreach(var item in new List<ItemType>(collection))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: It will still perform collection enumeration to create a list :)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - Yeah but this enumeration won't modify the contents of the original while it does so

Comment: As far as I understand the question, collection is not modified within the `foreach` loop, but from other source.

Comment: @Marcin Yes, but the whole point is that the foreach() no longer iterates over the original collection, just the same objects. If the original collection gets changed it doesnt affect the foreach().

Comment: Yes, but  there is still chance of getting the same error, if the change occurs when the list is created (`new List<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)` constructor will perform enumeration). It's less likely to happen, because time spend on that enumeration would probably be shorter then the original `foreach`, but still there is a risk of getting the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

There's two parts to your question, really. One is iteration on a changeable collection, but a hidden complexity is keeping your UI in sync with the changeable collection. For small collections and areas where performance isn't going to bite me in the bum, I'll throw a .ToList() on the end of the collection in the foreach.

```
foreach(var item in collection.ToList())
```

That way, it's iterating over a newly created collection rather than the base collection that gets changed all the time.

For the UI synchronization, though, you'll want to check that you haven't changed after iterating and that's a whole 'nother level of concern...

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem unable to lock out server changes while iterating over the collection, a couple of suggestions:

- Use `for (...)` or `while (...)` instead of `foreach (...)`, to avoid the enumerator's "collection was modified" exception. Note that you will need to handle changes to the collection, e.g. recheck the collection size at every iteration.
- If possible, only update the UI for *modified* items. What do you mean by "server push"? If your client app can listen for notifications from the server about modified items (including their indexes/IDs), then you only need to iterate over the collection once (initial UI load) using the above approach.